# Is it correct to specify HTTP response Content-Type as image/*?

Tags: http-headers, mime-types

I'm curious whether sending `Content-Type: image/*` in a HTTP response is correct. I know it's advisable to specify the exact MIME type but I'd like to hear if I can use such a header as a fallback when I know it's an image but I don't know its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any evidence that you can or should use wildcards in `Content-Type`.

RFC 7231 does allow wildcards like that in the [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header, where you're indicating a range of acceptable content types. The definition of [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) does not give any special meaning to the `*` character, and `image/*` is not listed as a [registered type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

If you cannot identify the media type accurately, you should just leave off the header entirely.